# Setting VideoView width and Height using code

Tags: android, height, width, android-videoview, dimensions

I want to set `VideoView` dimensions and I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. I don't see dimensions change when I run this code

```
package com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v8;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton floatButtonPlay;
    ImageButton floatButtonPause;
    ImageButton floatButtonBack;

    private Integer videos[];
    private Integer videos1[]={R.raw.vid4_1, R.raw.vid5_1_6m, R.raw.vid3_3m, R.raw.vid2_2_9m};
    private Integer videos2[]={R.raw.vts_0, R.raw.vts_1, R.raw.vts_5, R.raw.vts_6};


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein, R.anim.splashfadeout);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        floatButtonPlay=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        floatButtonPause=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        floatButtonPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        floatButtonBack=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backButton);


        final MyVideoView video1=(MyVideoView)findViewById(R.id.MyVideoView);

        videos= Arrays.copyOf(videos1,videos1.length);

        switch (MainActivity.AlbumChosed){

            case 1:
                videos= Arrays.copyOf(videos1,videos1.length);
                break;
            case 2:
                videos= Arrays.copyOf(videos2,videos2.length);
                break;

                default:
        }



        if (MainActivity.VidNum==MainActivity.vidPosition[0] ){
                                             setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

                    video1.setVideoSize(70,70);

                    video1.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + videos[0]);
                }

                else if 
    ........
    ........

        video1.start();

        video1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                floatButtonPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                floatButtonPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                floatButtonBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

        floatButtonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                floatButtonPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                floatButtonPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                video1.start();

            }
        } );

        floatButtonPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                floatButtonPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               ....
                if(video1.isPlaying()){
                    video1.pause();
                }          
            }
        } );

        floatButtonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein, R.anim.splashfadeout);


            }
        });



    }

    public class MyVideoView extends VideoView {

        private int mVideoWidth;
        private int mVideoHeight;

        public MyVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public MyVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public MyVideoView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public void setVideoSize(int width, int height) {
            mVideoWidth = width;
            mVideoHeight = height;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            // Log.i("@@@", "onMeasure");
            int width = getDefaultSize(mVideoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = getDefaultSize(mVideoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
            if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0) {
                if (mVideoWidth * height > width * mVideoHeight) {
                    // Log.i("@@@", "image too tall, correcting");
                    height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
                } else if (mVideoWidth * height < width * mVideoHeight) {
                    // Log.i("@@@", "image too wide, correcting");
                    width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
                } else {
                    // Log.i("@@@", "aspect ratio is correct: " +
                    // width+"/"+height+"="+
                    // mVideoWidth+"/"+mVideoHeight);
                }
            }
            // Log.i("@@@", "setting size: " + width + 'x' + height);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
    }

}
```

My XML is the next

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    tools:context="com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v8.VideoActivity">

    <com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v8.VideoActivity.MyVideoView

        android:id="@+id/MyVideoView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.428"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp" />

    <!-- "play" was taken from https://www.flaticon.com/ -->
    <!--    android:src="@mipmap/pause128"-->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
....
....
```

I get FATAL EXCEPTION

```
01-18 21:31:28.053 28639-28639/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6, PID: 28639
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v8.VideoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v8.VideoActivity.MyVideoView
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v8.VideoActivity.MyVideoView
                                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v8.VideoActivity.MyVideoView
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v8.VideoActivity.MyVideoView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v6-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
```

Comment: @propoLis I tried to implement your suggestion (as you can see at the updated code) but I get Unexpected cast to `MyVideoView`. Can you please suggest why. TNX

Comment: because your xml layout include VideoView not MyVideoView. 
You should be like this at xml layout:

`<com.nati_1.ImageGallerySwitching_v8.MyVideoView
app:width= "200dp" 
app:height = "200dp"/>`

Comment: you can see my edited answer

Comment: @propoLis implementing your suggestion cause to application STOPPED at the moment video should be played. I don't know why. Adding partial XML and logcat. I am not sure if `ConstraintLayout` is the problem...

Comment: can you please figure out the solution to the problem I face here

Comment: please remove your constraintlayout and sure that add myvideoview attributes

Comment: @propoLis do you mean I should use Relative layout instead of constraintlayout or just to remove the constraint attributes. sorry, just that I'm sort of newbe with programming.

Comment: can you see my edited answer